# Nginx HTTP/2 - Pingdom Test Not Working With SSL Enabled

Tags: nginx, https, http2

So I have a site setup in Nginx that was done using the Forge Laravel service. Without SSL enabled, the site loads fine for myself and also loads fine using the Pingdom Site Test.

If however I enable the SSL certificate, which is making use of HTTP/2 in the Nginx config then the site loads fine for myself but on Pingdom it gets a connection error and just shows the grey screenshot of the site can't be loaded. Is the site not falling back to HTTP/1.1 for some reason as I know that Pingdom doesn't support HTTP/2?

I've tested using Pingdom on every site I have on this server that has an SSL and I get the same result so I think it must be something to do with the way Laravel Forge has set something up as if I do a test on a SSL HTTP/2 site hosted elsewhere, Pingdom still works and is obviously falling back to HTTP/1.1

Here is the Nginx conf file for the site in question:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name cashbook.evaske.com;
    root /home/forge/cashbook.evaske.com/build;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cashbook.evaske.com/372692/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cashbook.evaske.com/372692/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/cashbook.evaske.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /$uri /index.html;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/cashbook.evaske.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Do you need to see any other config files from the server to help to work out why this is happening? The site loads fine through for example Google Page Test so I suspect it is something to do with HTTP/2 and not falling back to HTTP/1.1 for whatever reason?

Comment: can you try comment ssl-ciphers?

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev That seemed to make it work on Pingdom... question is now, what's wrong with the cipher line :D

Comment: can you post pingdom error?

Comment: https://help.pingdom.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001825505-SSL-Connection-Error-in-Root-Cause-Analysis

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev It's all working now. One of the ciphers must have been stopping the Pingdom test from loading the site properly. Not sure which one yet though.

Comment: nice. I am glad to solve the problem

Comment: Here's a list https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#BadCipherSuites